# Change DatagridviewTextBox Text When DatagridviewComboBox Selected Index Changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In My `DatagridView`,I Have Two Columns, `ComboxboxColumn` and `TextboxColumn`. I want to change the value of textbox 
when combobox selected index changes (in general combobox it has selected index change event but `datagridviewComboBox` does not have it)

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms, Silverlight, something else?

Comment: sorry its winforms,i tagged that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give these two simple methods a go (the '1' in the top method is the index of the combobox column)

The line that you would make you modifications to would be the setter line `cel.Value =`, as you may change it to whatever you like.

---

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
        var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
        cel.Value = sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString();
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: I wish I could score this more! Its helped me out a lot.