# Add DataGridViewComboBoxCell with different data sources to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I've already checked other posts but still could not fix my probem:
I have two forms:

- One that creates clients ( can have multiple phones, addresses and cars)
- A main form which should display each client info.

[image]

First of all, is it possible to have a client in each row, and the three combos (phones, addresses, and cars) with each clients info?

For example:

I've got two clients, John and Jack, and I want the rows displayed like this:

0  - John - John.Phones - John.Addresses - John.Cars
1  -  Jack - Jack.Phones - Jack.Addresses - Jack.Cars

Also, I don't know what should I pass to my row as argument for the combobox, should I pass the dataSource, Items, or the combo itself? Whatever I pass for the comboboxes, I get: 
 `System.ArgumentException: DatagridViewRowComboBoxCell value is not valid`

Here's the actual code.

```
private DataGridViewRow BuildRow(Cliente cliente)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();           
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell Autos = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();


    Autos.DataSource = cliente.Autos;
    Autos.ValueMember = cliente.Autos[0].ToString();
    row.CreateCells(DGCliente, cliente.Codigo.ToString(), cliente.Nombre, Autos);
    row.Tag = cliente;
    DGCliente.Rows.Add(row);

    return row;
}
```

Client class code: (spanish)

```
public class Cliente
{
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public Int32 Codigo { get; set; }
    public List<Auto> Autos { get; set; }
    public List<Direccion> Direcciones { get; set; }
    public List<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }

    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Direcciones = new List<Direccion>();
        this.Telefonos = new List<Telefono>();
        this.Autos = new List<Auto>();

    }

    public Cliente(String Nombre , Int32 Codigo)
    {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
        this.Direcciones = new List<Direccion>();
        this.Telefonos = new List<Telefono>();
        this.Autos = new List<Auto>();
    }

    public void AgregarTelefono(bool esCelular, String numero, String area)
    { 
       this.Telefonos.Add(new Telefono(esCelular, numero, area));
    }

    public void AgregarDireccion(string calle, string altura, string localidad, string provincia)
    {
        this.Direcciones.Add(new Direccion(calle, altura, localidad, provincia));
    }

    public void AgregarAuto(Auto auto)
    {
        this.Autos.Add(auto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning the row if the method adds it already (or vice versa if you want) ? Also, naming of vars is lacking. What is `Autos`? you use it as a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell ` (DGVCBC for short) and also as a property on your Cliente object? Can you post the Cliente code?

Comment: Autos was just the name I wanted to give the combo I wanna add to my row, should name it DGVCBCAutos I guess

Comment: You should have, indeed :). Anyways, now you call your Client ctor with twice, and add some phones, addresses and cars, right? And then when you call the buildrow, it crashes I assume. Can you post the initialization code, or is it from a db? (so I can test it here). (and why altura and not numero for direccion??)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question. Of course you can. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277632/change-datagridviewtextbox-text-when-datagridviewcombobox-selected-index-changes/11277733#11277733), or at any other StackOverflow with that tag.

The real problem is the **how**. Most of the posts are WPF related, in which case the binding would have helped, but I highly suggest having a read through [this guy's blog](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20060202.asp) where he's having an example with code for a similar result.

Suerte :)

**Edit:**
Your `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` source should be an `IList` or `IListSource` that contains a collection of values used to supply data to the drop-down list (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't believe me).

So, each of your objects should have a property which is a `List` or whatever you would like that satisfies the `IList` interface, and you should bind that to your source.

So, for example, if the following class is your object, you should bind that object to the row, but specifically BindToThis1 (&2) to your DataGridViewComboBoxCell sources (like he did in the example with `dtTitles`).

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<string> BindToThis1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> BindToThis2 { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        BindToThis1 = new List<string> { "hello", "world" };
        BindToThis2 = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "green" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I need different datasources for different comboboxes, and the example in the blog only has one and it's for the whole column. Also I need to create a row with my client's data, and I don't know what argument to pass.

Comment: I already did that, the client class has 3 properties which are collections, (list <car> , <phone> and <address>) still can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a row for every client with 2 types of cell a textbox cell and a combobox cell.
Consider the following :

```
 public class PersonRow : DataGridViewRow
    {
        public DataGridViewTextBoxCell Name;
        public DataGridViewComboBoxCell Phones;
        public DataGridViewComboBoxCell Cars;

        public PersonRow(Person person)
        {
            Name.Value = person.Name;

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell phones = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            phones.Items.AddRange((DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ObjectCollection)person.Phones); //add the items from Person.Phones to PersonRow.Phones combobox cell

            Phones = phones;

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cars = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cars.Items.AddRange((DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ObjectCollection)person.Cars); //add Person.Cars to PersonRow.Cars combobox cell 

            Cars = cars;

            Cells.AddRange(new DataGridViewCell[] { Name, Phones, Cars }); //add cells to the row

        }
    }

public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Phones>  Phones { get; set; } //be sure to use the IList interface
        public IList<Cars> Cars { get; set; } //be sure to implement the IList interface

        public Person( string name, List<Phones> phones, List<Cars> cars)
        {
            Name = name;
            Phones = phones;
            Cars = cars;
        }
    }

public class Phones
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public Phones(string name, string model)
        {
            Name = name;
            Model = model;

        }
    }

    public class Cars
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public Cars(string name, string model)
        {
            Name = name;
            Model = model;
        }
    }
```

Also checkout :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3sctb6(v=vs.110).aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx
Hope this helps!